# Listing the Dimensions of an Antenna in a Paper using the Latex

Tags: dimensions

I have been trying to insert the table of dimensions of an antenna in a latex code. I used the code

```
{
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l | l | l | l | l}
Reference Number & BW (GhHz) & Antenna size (mm3) & Gain & Notched Bands (GHz) \\
\hline
[20] & 2.3-13.75  & 39*39*1 pt 6 & 1 pt 4-46 & 2 pt 25-3.75
5.08-5.9
7.06-7.95
 \\
[21] & 3.11-13.15 & 28*52*1.6 & 1.53-4.05 & 5.1-5.92 \\
[22] & 2.8-14 & 27*36*1.6 & N/A & 3.26-3.9
4.35-5.05
5.5-6.35
7.95-9.35
 \\
Current Work & 3.1 – 17 & 24*28*1.6 & 4.5-8 & 3.2-3.9
7.2-8.5

\end{tabular}
\caption{Comparison of the suggested antenna to antennas in previous literature}
\end{table}
}
```

But the error:

{
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).

> 

l.83 [21]
& 3 pt 11-13 pt 15 & 28*52*1 pt 6 & 1 pt 53-4 pt 05 & 5 pt 1-5 pt ...
Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

}
kept showing. How can I simply insert the dimension of an item in a table

Comment: This question is duplicate to your previous. So, consider comment to it. BTW, always please provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document which start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`

Comment: Off topic:  since `table` is a float,  wrapping it in braces doesn't do anything useful, and may, in fact, result in an unwanted space in the output.